# the time complexity difference between using arrays and vectors

Tags: c++

for the question finding nth ugly number(whose prime factorisation only contains 2,3,5 ) (1 included).when i used the below solution using vectors the time taken is >1.013 which showed TLE but when i used arrays the time taken is 0.9 which got accepted! can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define llb long long int
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        llb ugly[n]; // To store ugly numbers 
        llb i2 = 0, i3 = 0, i5 = 0; 
        llb next_multiple_of_2 = 2; 
        llb next_multiple_of_3 = 3; 
        llb next_multiple_of_5 = 5; 
        llb next_ugly_no = 1; 
      
        ugly[0] = 1; 
        for (int i=1; i<n; i++) 
        { 
           next_ugly_no = min(next_multiple_of_2, 
                               min(next_multiple_of_3, 
                                   next_multiple_of_5)); 
           ugly[i] = next_ugly_no; 
           if (next_ugly_no == next_multiple_of_2) 
           { 
               i2 = i2+1; 
               next_multiple_of_2 = ugly[i2]*2; 
           } 
           if (next_ugly_no == next_multiple_of_3) 
           { 
               i3 = i3+1; 
               next_multiple_of_3 = ugly[i3]*3; 
           } 
           if (next_ugly_no == next_multiple_of_5) 
           { 
               i5 = i5+1; 
               next_multiple_of_5 = ugly[i5]*5; 
           } 
        } /*End of for loop (i=1; i<n; i++) */
        cout<<next_ugly_no<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any use of `vector` in the code shown.

Comment: `llb ugly[n];` where `n` is a variable determined at run time is not valid C++.  You're relying on a non-standard compiler extension.  Any explanation of why it performs bettter than alternatives will need to consider specifics of how your compiler and host system handle such things versus how the standard container does things.   In any event, you need to focus on the algorithm (the logic of how you calculate results) at least as much as how the containers work.

Comment: Use a using alias or at minimum a typedef for llb. Using the preprocessor to define a type alias is a bad idea

Comment: You show us the code that works better, and ask us why the code we cannot see is less efficient??? We're supposed to guess what you did sub-optimally?

Comment: @JaMiT sorry for that,anyway its just replacing int ugly[n] with vector<int>ugly(n).

Answer (score 1):

The performance should be virtually identical if you write the code correctly.

What is *likely* happening (since you don't show the other case) is that in the `std::vector` case you are re-allocating many times, probably by re-creating the object on every outer loop iteration. If you re-use the object, then you should see very similar performance.

---

Side note:

```
llb ugly[n]; // To store ugly numbers
```

This is non-standard C++: a Variable Length Array (VLA).